# Receiving image from Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to get at photo from an azure ad using microsoft graph api.

I make the request to api. I know the uri is correct. When i try it with correct security token in Postman the photo is displayed. When i try the same uri in microsofts graph explorer online i as well see the image. When i look at the sourcode i can see an image tag with the followin src

```
<img src="blob:https://developer.microsoft.com/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx">
```

But when i make the call from a net core 2 backend i cant manage to get anything usefull. Im not sure what im supposed to use to receive the blob or how to handle the blob. How do i receive a blob from microsoft graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph explorer converts the API response to a `blob`. This `blob` object has a URL that can be the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag.

Graph explorer is open source and if you know a bit of javascript this might be an example worth looking at.  We convert the Graph API response to a blob at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/blob/e2a376615d14c5eabd51e972478b18827800d323/src/app/query-runner.service.ts#L116

For asp .net core, maybe look at the [aspnetcore-connect-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample)? They convert the photo response to base64 at  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/blob/41e6cfeae6d6fb0035a188f066d56de1ad697841/MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample/Helpers/GraphService.cs#L54

Comment: Thank you! Great lead. Im looking into it.

Comment: Thanks dude! I uploaded a complete workaround for images here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181438/parse-image-from-microsoft-graph-api