# Parse Image from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: image, binary, base64, blob

After i looked up the www, stackoverflow and youtube, i couldn't find an concrete answer about, how to fetch an image correctly from:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value
```

in TypeScript/JavaScript. The solution is really easier as i thought. You just need this an additional information in your `GET` Request:

```
responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution looks like this:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Http, Headers, ResponseContentType } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular";

export class GraphService {
constructor(
   private http: Http,
   private alertCtrl: AlertController,
   private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
) {}

transform(html) {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(html);
}

getProfileImage(accessToken: string) {
    // fetch User Profile Image
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    this.http
      .get("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value", {
        responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer,
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          let blob = new Blob([data.arrayBuffer()], {
            type: data.headers.get("content-type")
          });
          let imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          return this.transform(imageUrl));
        },
        error => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: "GraphProvider",
            subTitle: "Can't fetch profile image!",
            buttons: ["OK"]
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      );
}
}
```

The most important part is: don't append the `responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer` in your header! You have to provide it beside the header! And don't forget to import it from `@angular/http`!

I hope I could help all the lost souls out there :D

PS: Thanks to Micheal Mainer for the Graph Explorer Repo: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/tree/e2a376615d14c5eabd51e972478b18827800d323

here's my fetched Image from Microsoft Graph API:

[image]